# Merging two composable walks in a graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, notation

Let $G$ be a graph (i.e., an undirected graph in which we allow for loops and parallel edges). Denote by $V$ the vertex set, by $E$ the edge set, and by $\psi$ the incidence function of $G$, and let $\mathscr F(X)$ be the free monoid over a set $X$. I'll write $\ast_X$ for the operation of (**word**) **concatenation** in $\mathscr F(X)$ and omit the subscript $X$ if there is no risk of confusion.

Formally speaking, a **walk** (in the graph $G$) is a non-empty word $\mathfrak z = z_0 \ast \cdots \ast z_k \in \mathscr F(V \cup E)$ of *odd* length $k+1$ such that

- $z_{2i} \in V$ for each $i \in [\![0, k/2 ]\!]$, and
- $z_{2i+1} \in E$ and $\psi(z_{2i+1}) = \{z_{2i}, z_{2i+2}\}$ for each $i \in [\![0, k/2-1 ]\!]$.

Just in case, note that the length of $\mathfrak z$ as a $(V \cup E)$-word is not the same as the length of $\mathfrak z$ as a walk, which, by definition, is rather equal to $k/2$.

Now, the concatenation $\mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak v$ of a walk $\mathfrak u = u_0 \ast \cdots \ast u_h$ of length $h$ with a walk $\mathfrak v = v_0 \ast \cdots \ast v_k$ of length $k$ is not a walk (regardless of any restrictions on $\mathfrak u$ and $\mathfrak v$). However, if $(\mathfrak u, \mathfrak v)$ is a pair of **composable walks** in the sense that the origin $v_0$ of $\mathfrak v$ and the terminus $u_h$ of $\mathfrak v$ coincide, then the concatenation of $\mathfrak u$ with the subword of $\mathfrak v$ obtained from pruning $v_0$ off of $\mathfrak v$ is a walk (with origin $u_0$ and terminus $v_k$), herein denoted by $\mathfrak u \circ_G \mathfrak v$ and called the **$G$-composition** of $\mathfrak u$ with $\mathfrak v$.

> **Question.** Is there a standard name for the partial (binary) operation that maps a pair of composable walks to their $G$-composition?
> Is there a standard notation for this composition? And is there any textbook on graph theory where things are
> worked out *more or less* in these terms?

"Composition" sounds like a natural name to me, since the walks of the graph $G$ can be viewed as the morphisms of a category whose objects are the vertices of $G$ and where the composition law is precisely the partial operation that maps a pair of composable walks to their $G$-composition. But I'd like to hear from the graph theorists.

Comment: It is usually called concatenation if the result is a walk, and not mentioned at all if it isn't.  I don't recall anyone ever having a need for "concatenating" walks except to make a walk. But then I don't usually read category theory.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay It's probably another instance of the phenomenon by which certain concepts were first considered and then consolidated long before the emergence of a new (and more general) point of view that would have possibly suggested a different (and more natural?) terminology. As for the rest, path algebras is one situation where it makes sense to consider the composition of two walks regardless of whether one is ending where the other is starting, up to the fact that, in a path algebra, we work with a quiver/(multi)digraph rather than with a (multi)graph.